About the std::generator Yielded type
According cppreference the std::generator Yielded type definition is:
using Yielded = conditional_t<is_reference_v<Reference>, Reference, const Reference&>;

I wrote the simplest test:
#include <generator>
#include <string>

template <typename T> std::generator<T> my_gen_T()
{
    std::string value("value ");
    co_yield value;
}

void test_gen_ref()
{
    auto my_gen_instance = my_gen_T<std::string&>();
    for (auto&& elem : my_gen_instance)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::string&, decltype(elem)>); //OK
    }
}

void test_gen_const_ref()
{
    auto my_gen_instance = my_gen_T<const std::string&>();
    for (auto&& elem : my_gen_instance)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<const std::string&, decltype(elem)>); //OK
    }
}

void test_gen_value()
{
    auto my_gen_instance = my_gen_T<std::string>();
    for (auto&& elem : my_gen_instance)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<const std::string&, decltype(elem)>); //FAILED
    }
}

int main()
{
}

and was very surprised by the result of the static_assert from the function void test_gen_value()
Where did I go wrong? (The compiler version is gcc 14.1.0 (for Windows)).

The iterator does not produce a yielded, but a reference. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator/iterator#dereference.
If only one template argument T is given to the generator then reference is T&&. In your failing test case that means std::string&&, causing elem to have type std::string&& as well.
yielded is just used internally to make sure that the generator only needs to store a pointer rather than a copy of the yielded object when that is sufficient.
Also, because reference is std::string&& in the example in question, yielded is also std::string&&.
